# How to unhide user removed aggregations

Tags: facebook, aggregation, facebook-timeline

I came across an issue where, just to try it out, I removed an aggregation from a timeline app. I then was unable to get the aggregation back.

Steps to take:

1. add an app to your timeline (For example http://pose.com)
2. create some actions
3. once an aggregation shows up in the timeline app, remove it by clicking the edit icon in the title bar of the aggregation. Note: do not hide the 'recent activity' but hide any other aggregation

From a user's perspective: how can a user unhide this aggregation?

- I have looked in the app-settings ('Account Settings' > 'Apps') but there are no options for aggregations.
- removing the app, and then adding it again also does not work. Recent activities show fine, but any other aggregations have disappeared

From an app's perspective: how can an app unhide this aggregation?

- can I see (API call) which aggregations have been hidden by the user?
- can I then ask the users to un-hide the aggregation?
- is there an API call do un-hide an aggregation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**From a user's perspective:**

1. From your profile page, click on the "Activity Log" link;
2. Find the application whose activity box you want restored from the column on the left and click on it;
3. A little icon will appear on the top right - click on it to decide what kind of app activity gets shown and to restore any type of activity you previously hid.

[image]

**From an app's perspective:**

As for now, no API calls have been created to deal with aggregations.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi ancelotavery, thanx for the solution. I hope FB will add this option to the API as it is very easy for a user to remove an aggregation, but I can hardly ask him to go through all these steps to reset it.